# Which preposition should follow the adjective 'learned'?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Consider the definition of [learned](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/learned) (as an adjective) as provided by the Cambridge Dictionary:

> A learned person has studied for a long time and has a lot of knowledge

I am interested in the case that is followed by a preposition. For example:

> He is learned *in*/*on*/*about* mathematics

Which preposition should be used after the adjective **learned** as in the above example?

Comment: You mean _preposition_ right?

Comment: A google books search suggests  “learned in” is the more common collocaction. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+learned+in%2Che+is+learned+on%2Che+is+learned+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20is%20learned%20in%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I don't think you can add any kind of qualifier in the first place. It seams to me that [*learned*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/learned), as an adjective, is an all or nothing description. *He **is** learned.* [Period.] *He (has knowledge of / has studied) mathematics.* It's the same type of absolute adjective as *he is tall*. You can't add a modifier after *tall*, only before. Using it as a *verb*, however, you can say that *he **has** learned mathematics*, but there would be no preposition involved. You could use it's noun form. *He has **learning** in mathematics.*

Comment: @DW256 I used 'postposition' because in my mind it is after 'learned'. But I suppose it is a 'preposition' before the subject that one is learned in. Please correct it if you are more learned than me as to whether it should be preposition or postposition.

Comment: @egg From _The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar_:  In some languages (e.g. Japanese) the kinds of meaning and function
that prepositions have in English are exhibited by words that follow their
complements, and these are appropriately called postpositions (e.g. the
equivalent of _the bath in_, rather than _in the bath_). Such a class of words
does not exist in English, though some words, e.g. ago (as in a _month ago_),
notwithstanding (as in _his efforts notwithstanding_), and *enclitics (-n’t, -’s)
are sometimes so described.

Comment: @DW256 Thanks for that. I did not realise that English does not have postpositions. I assumed that if I was using a preposition after the word of interest then it would be called a postposition but this is not the case. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjective *learned* takes a prepositional phrase complement headed by *in* or *about*. There seems to be a difference in usage: *in* is used with a field of study whereas *about* is used with things more concrete.

> *By the Senior year he had already become learned **in** Logic, and a master of the devices of Oratory*
>
> *The mind becomes learned **in** many things having once consented to be ignorant of some*
>
> *As Jennifer becomes learned **about** her adopted city*
>
> *It is also perpetuated to ensure that mankind never becomes learned
>   **about** the true nature, cause and cure of disease.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am hoping for a more complete answer. For instance in the comments Jason Bassford has written that use of prepositions after learned is non-standard in the first place. Could you address whether prepositions should be used at all with 'learned'?

Comment: I'm surprised at the  "non-standard" remark. In British and American English "learned in" is rather old-fashioned. OED: **Having profound knowledge gained by study, esp. in language or some department of literary or historical science. erudite... Constructed with *in***, // 1712  Remarks & Coll. He was *learned in* the British tongue. 1610  Brit.  Sundry ceremonies, which I leave to *the learned in* Christian antiquities. // 2001 Epic India:  a Brahmin who was *learned in* one Veda only was usually fair and one who was *learned in* three Vedas was dark in complexion .

Comment: @egg I don't have an authoritative source for the use of _learned_ with _about_. However, google books turns up ample results from different time periods, so it seems to be an established use. From a letter written by T.E. Lawrence: _I become learned about boats, and meanwhile, there are no books, no music, no easements._